# Not unique table/alias 'GPS'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Here is the creation of my table :

```
  "CREATE TABLE GPS ("+
               "id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
               "name VARCHAR(30),"+
               "x REAL,"+"y REAL,"+
               "PRIMARY KEY (id)"+")";
```

I hanve this query and when I'm trying to execute it , there is an Exception "Not unique table/alias"
I try to change everything but the exception still remains !

```
"SELECT GPS.ID,GPS.NAME,GPS.X,GPS.Y,POI.ID,"+
                "POI.TYPE FROM GPS JOIN POI"+
                "ON POI.ID=GPS.ID"+
                "WHERE("+ 
                "(X BETWEEN "+xaxis+"-"+sett.getR()+" AND "+xaxis+"+"+sett.getR()+
                ") AND (Y BETWEEN "+yaxis+"-"+sett.getR()+" AND "+yaxis+"+"+sett.getR()+"))";
```

Comment: You should really use Prepared Statements instead of patching things together like this.

Comment: Besides the error message produced by the query, also check the actual query that ends up being executed so you can check for trivial errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have spaces in the actual query, like :

```
"POI.TYPE FROM GPS JOIN POI"+"ON POI.ID=GPS.ID
"POI.TYPE FROM GPS JOIN POI"+" ON POI.ID=GPS.ID
```

This will result in the actual query being :

SELECT GPS.ID,GPS.NAME,GPS.X,GPS.Y,POI.ID,POI.TYPE FROM **GPS JOIN POION POI.ID**=GPS.ID (...)

I dont think POION is the table name.

Comment: I don't understand you ! Be more specific please !

Comment: Your actual query will end up like this: SELECT GPS.ID,GPS.NAME,GPS.X,GPS.Y,POI.IDPOI.TYPE FROM GPS JOIN POION POI.ID=GPS.ID // and i think POION is not a table ...

Comment: this is about as specific as it gets, they gave you the code as well?

Comment: You also missed the space before `WHERE`

Comment: Thank you are right ! I haven't seen the mistake in the concatenation and , if you would write the query that I execute in reality , I wouldn't !

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for create query is correct just try,
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GPS` 
Before executing create table query.

Comment: Create table query has nothing to do with his problem. The problem query is the select one.

Comment: I have done ! The exeption appears again

Comment: Try selecting some hardcoded values in select query to confirm if there is an issue with your select query.